# Scroll to fixed navigation loads at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I am using joomla! 3, I have an icemega menu and it uses a jquery scroll-to-fixed to collect the navigation on the way down.

In Chrome:
When the site loads on the homepage it loads and works fine; when i navigate to a different page the navigation loads with the scroll-to-fixed class already added so the navigation is at the top of the browser window. This also now occurs on the homepage if you navigate back to the homepage.

In Firefox:
It seems to have a separate problem; the scroll snaps to the top too soon.

Both browsers issues are rectified if inspect element is opened and then closed.

The homepage banner (layerslider) is larger in height so I tried to increase the height of the rest of the sites banner but that had no effect.

The website is :http://multi.multi-web-service.co.uk/

Thanks

Comment: #navigation {
  margin-top: 0;
} remove this style

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed that now; no difference. The jquery still loads the page with the scroll-to-fixed class added. Which should not happen until the page is scrolled down to a certain position.